# How to identify if a value is integer or number?

Tags: robotframework

I want to identify if a value stored in a variable is an integer or not. If its an integer then it should return a Boolean value

I have tried using *Built-In* functions like `Should be Equal As Numbers`, `Should be Equal As Integers` but they did not work.

Since I am not so sound in Python, hence I was not able to make use of the Python built-in functions but I have a strong feeling that python functions like `.isdigit()` or `.isnumeric()` can come in handy here.

I am storing some value in a variable, say `${TestVariable}`
Now, I have tried identifying the stored value as integer via following ways:

```
${Status}   Run Keyword and Return Status   Should be Equal As Numbers   ${TestVariable}   1
Log to Console   \n ${TestVariable}-${Status}
```

And I have passed values like

> a,b,1,2

Since I have hard coded value 1 in `Should Be Equal As Numbers`, hence it returned `True` when the value stored in `${TestVariable}` is ***1*** but returned `False` when the value was ***2***

Actual Result:

```
a-False
b-False
1-True
2-False
```

Expected Result:
I want Robot to return True when value is a number and False when its a character like below

```
a-False
b-False
1-True
2-True
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of your Python code?

Comment: Hi @N.Arunoprayoch 
I am trying to achieve it in Robot Framework. But I am not aware of the syntax to use .isdigit() in RF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, please note that "2e10" is converted to number, but the keyword does not consider that.

```
*** Test Cases***
Verify Types
    FOR    ${item}    IN    two    ${None}    1235    2.567    2e10
        ${result}=    Check Type    ${item}
        Log    Item ${item} is ${result}
    END

*** Keywords ***
Check Type
    [Arguments]    ${object}
    [Documentation]    Checks if the ${object } is INTEGER, NUMBER or STRING
    Return From Keyword If    not "${object}"    NONE
    ${result}    ${value}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Convert To Number    ${object}
    ${isnumber}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${object}    ${value}
    ${result}    ${value}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Convert To Integer    ${object}
    ${isinteger}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${object}    ${value}
    Return From Keyword If    ${isnumber}    NUMBER
    Return From Keyword If    ${isinteger}    INTEGER
    Return From Keyword    STRING
```

Comment: Hi @Helio,
I didnt understand the below line of code:
${result}    ${value}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Convert To Number    ${object}

What is going to be stored in ${result) and ${value}?

Comment: @SamadhiGhosh As you can see in documentation, the ${result} is PASS or FAIL and the ${value} is the converted value or error message. Running the example and observing the Log.html should make it clear. See http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error

Comment: Hi @Helio,
A year back, I came across this function 'Run Keyword and Ignore Error' but never cared to understand the same and have ignored but I feel sorry now. I ran the above 'Check Type' keyword and it returned INTEGER or STRING - which will solve my purpose. I envy you for your knowledge :) Wish I will become an expert like you one day.

Answer (score -2):

```
if type(a) == int:
    print('the value is integer')
a = "sabuj"
if type(a) == str:
    print('the value is string')
a = [1,2,3]
if type(a) == list: 
    print('the value is List')
```

Comment: If it's an integer then it should return a Boolean value which is not what this code does.